# Set last position when scroll load more recycleview

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to implement load more recycleview It's working fine but when scroll recycleview at that time always first item is top of the view, I want next scrollable item at the top, How can I solve this problem, Please help me

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int page_no = 0;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<NotificationBean> mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    private NotificationBean mNotificationBean;
    private int loadMoreArrayListSize;
    public int arrayListSize;
    // private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
//        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
//        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        getData(MainActivity.this, page_no, "4");
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter();
        mUserAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                Log.e("haint", "Load More");
                mUsers.add(null);
                mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1);

                //Load more data for reyclerview
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("haint", "Load More 2");

                        //Remove loading item
                        mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
                        mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());

                        //Load data
                        page_no++;
                        //callAPI(1);
                        //  Log.d("arrTemp Position: : ", String.valueOf(arrTemp));
                        getData(MainActivity.this, page_no, "4");
                        // mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(mUsers.size() - 10, 0);
                        Log.v("LoadMoreListener arsize", Integer.toString(mUsers.size()));
                        loadMoreArrayListSize = arrayListSize - mUsers.size();
                        Log.v("loadMoreArrayListSize", Integer.toString(loadMoreArrayListSize));

                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgView;
        public TextView txtComment, txtParamLink, txtTitle, txtVideoId;

        public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtComment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtComment);
            txtParamLink = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtParamLink);
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtVideoId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoId);
            imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        }
    }

    static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }

    class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

        private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;

        private boolean isLoading;
        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
        private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

        public UserAdapter() {
            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
            this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return mUsers.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.notification_item, parent, false);
                return new UserViewHolder(view);
            } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_item, parent, false);
                return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (holder instanceof UserViewHolder) {
                NotificationBean user = mUsers.get(position);
                UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
//                userViewHolder.tvName.setText(user.getName());
//                userViewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(user.getEmail());
                userViewHolder.txtComment.setText(Integer.toString(user.getComment()));
                userViewHolder.txtParamLink.setText(user.getPermalink());
                userViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(user.getTitle());
                userViewHolder.txtVideoId.setText(user.getVideoid());
                if (user.getImage() != null) {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(user.getImage()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).dontAnimate().into(userViewHolder.imgView);
                }
            } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
                LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
                loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mUsers == null ? 0 : mUsers.size();
        }

        public void setLoaded() {
            isLoading = false;
        }
    }

    private void getData(Context context, final int posts_per_page, final String type) {

//        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
//        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//        pDialog.show();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
//        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://asiatube.info/sgtube/api/ws.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://steanrewards.com/api/ws.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                JSONArray jArray;
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    int code = jObj.getInt("code");
                    if (code == 0) {
                        Log.d("allcount:: :: ::", String.valueOf(jObj.optInt("allcount")));
                        if (jObj.has("result")) {
                            jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
                            Log.d("EVENTLIST ARRAY=", jsonArray.length() + "");

                            if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {

//                                arrTemp = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    mNotificationBean = new NotificationBean();
                                    mNotificationBean.id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                                    mNotificationBean.permalink = jsonObject.getString("permalink");
                                    mNotificationBean.image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                                    mNotificationBean.title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                                    mNotificationBean.videotype = jsonObject.getString("videotype");
                                    mNotificationBean.videoid = jsonObject.getString("videoid");
                                    mNotificationBean.desc = jsonObject.getString("desc");
                                    mNotificationBean.author_url = jsonObject.getString("author_url");
                                    mNotificationBean.like = jsonObject.getString("like");
                                    mNotificationBean.unlike = jsonObject.getString("unlike");
                                    mNotificationBean.comment = jsonObject.getInt("comment");
                                    //arrTemp.add(mNotificationBean);
                                    mUsers.add(mNotificationBean);
                                    Log.v("ArrayList Size:: :: ", Integer.toString(mUsers.size()));
                                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
                                    mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    mUserAdapter.setLoaded();

                                }
                                Log.v("mUsers Size:: :: ", Integer.toString(mUsers.size()));
                                arrayListSize = mUsers.size();
                            }
                            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                                    mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(mArrayList);
                            // pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override

            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("posts_per_page", Integer.toString(posts_per_page));
                params.put("type", type);
//                params.put("fromsite", fromsite);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                15000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        queue.add(sr);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading you must be knowing the position of top element of new loaded items. just call:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

And you can use it whenever you want to show specific item on current view, just call this function with their list position. For example you are loading new item after every 80 items so, position of newly loaded item will be 80 so you can call:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(80);
```

Just keep on updating this position as you load more and more items.

Comment: Can you please help me how to get position of top element of new loaded items

Comment: it will be the size of arrayList before loading more items. Let's you are loading more items and already you have 100 elements in your list so 100 will be the position of top elements. And yes notifyDataSetChanged() will do the job, no need to set adapter again after every addition of elements.

Comment: Are you sure you did exactly what I suggested? Because what I think is you didn't get my answer.

Comment: Yes I follow your answer look I refresh 10 records every time.
mUsers.add(mNotificationBean);
 position =  mUsers.size();                                                      
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
 /*mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
mUserAdapter.setLoaded();
and this position I passed in loadmore listener
mUsers.add(mNotificationBean);
position =  mUsers.size();                                                                    
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter); mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Okay when you are refreshing store the position of first completely visible position, you can get that by `linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();` and then after refreshing use to scroll to that particularly item.

Comment: I noticed in your previous comment that you are calculating the position to scroll after adding new items, instead your position should be the size before adding new items. Let's say you had 15 items and you are refreshing to add 10 more, in that case position should be 10 not 25.

Answer (score 0):

although,`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);` is a **quick fix** i would suggest you **don't use it**, genrally this happens when you do `setAdapter()` again after the pagination, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` after the new data is got

Comment: So can you please suggest me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try writing the onscroll method outside the adapter, as everything else looks fine